# Insert VALUES from query multi row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "RESULT" with this column:

```
+--------+------+------------+--------+
| USERID | POIN |    DATE    |  DESC  |
+--------+------+------------+--------+
|      1 |   10 | 2015-08-03 | LOGIN  |
|      1 |   -1 | 2015-08-11 | LOGOUT |
|      3 |    5 | 2015-08-07 | INVITE |
|      2 |   30 | 2015-08-15 | LOGIN  |
|      2 |    5 | 2015-08-17 | INVITE |
|      2 |    3 | 2015-08-25 | LOGOUT |
+--------+------+------------+--------+
```

So, I want to insert new values to table "RESULT". So this is new values:

```
+--------+------+------------+--------+
| USERID | POIN |    DATE    |  DESC  |
+--------+------+------------+--------+
|      1 |    9 | 2015-09-01 | FREE   |
|      3 |    5 | 2015-09-01 | FREE   |
|      2 |   38 | 2015-09-01 | FREE   |
+--------+------+------------+--------+
```

DATE and DESC defined value, but poin is sum result. How to do this in postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to insert new rows with sum of the poin value and a fixed date and desc value.

You can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO RESULT ("USERID", "POIN", "DATE", "DESC")
SELECT "USERID", SUM("POIN"), '2015-09-01', 'FREE'
FROM RESULT GROUP BY "USERID";
```

If you want to see what rows would be inserted you can run the statement without the first line.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/74a25/1)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this query show error:
[SQL]INSERT RESULT ("USERID", "POIN", "DATE", "DESC")
SELECT "USERID", SUM("POIN"), '2015-09-01', 'FREE'
FROM RESULT GROUP BY "USERID";

[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RESULT"
LINE 1: INSERT RESULT ("USERID", "POIN", "DATE", "DESC")
               ^

Comment: @bandungeuy Oh, I forgot the `into` keyword (it's optional in may other databases but not in Postgresql). I've updated the query.